# How do I convert a Rust closure to a C-style callback?

Tags: rust, closures, ffi

I'm trying to write a Rusty wrapper for a piece of C API. There is one C construct I struggle with:

```
typedef bool (*listener_t) (int, int);
bool do_it(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, listener_t listener)
```

The function does its job for a range of numbers unless the listener returns false. In that case it aborts computation. I want to have a Rust wrapper like this:

```
fn do_with_callback<F>(start: (i32, i32), end: (i32, i32), callback: F)
    where F: Fn(i32, i32) -> bool
```

`rust-bindgen` created this for me, slightly edited for clarity:

```
pub type listener_t = Option<extern "C" fn(x: c_int, y: c_int) -> c_bool>;

pub fn TCOD_line(xFrom: c_int, yFrom: c_int,
                 xTo: c_int, yTo: c_int,
                 listener: listener_t) -> c_bool;
```

How should I convert a closure or a trait reference to a C-style callback in my `do_with` functions:

```
pub fn do_with_callback<F>(start: (i32, i32), end: (i32, i32), callback: F) -> Self
    where F: Fn(i32, i32) -> bool
{
    let wrapper = ???;
    unsafe {
        ffi::do_it(start.0, start.1, end.0, end.1, Some(wrapper))
    };
}
```

Comment: How does a C client of this library pass caller-specific information? This seems like an example of an API that simply wasn't designed to allow that. Perhaps the API authors believe that it's not needed, and that you can make all decisions you need based on `(x, y)`.

Comment: Well, the C library is not particularly well designed. It relies a lot on `static`s and global state. And it doesn't even try to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You cannot do it unless the C API allows passing a user-provided callback parameter. If it does not, you can only use static functions.

The reason is that closures are not "just" functions. As their name implies, closures "close over" variables from their lexical scope. Each closure has an associated piece of data which holds either values of captured variables (if the `move` keyword is used) or references to them. This data can be thought of as some unnamed, anonymous `struct`.

The compiler automatically adds an implementation of the corresponding `Fn*` traits for these anonymous structs. [As you can see](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), methods on these traits accept `self` in addition to the closure arguments. In this context, `self` is the `struct` on which the trait is implemented. This means that each function which corresponds to a closure also has an additional parameter which contains the closure environment.

If your C API only allows you to pass functions without any user-defined parameters, you cannot write a wrapper which would allow you to use closures. I guess it *may* be possible to write some global holder for the closures environment, but I doubt it would be easy and safe.

If your C API does allow passing a user-defined argument, then it is possible to do what you want with trait objects:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::mem;

use libc::{c_int, c_void};

extern "C" {
    fn do_something(f: Option<extern "C" fn(x: c_int, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int>, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int;
}

extern "C" fn do_something_handler(x: c_int, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
    let closure: &mut &mut dyn FnMut(i32) -> bool = unsafe { mem::transmute(arg) };
    closure(x as i32) as c_int
}

pub fn do_with_callback<F>(x: i32, mut callback: F) -> bool
    where F: FnMut(i32) -> bool
{
    // reason for double indirection is described below
    let mut cb: &mut dyn FnMut(i32) -> bool = &mut callback;
    let cb = &mut cb;
    unsafe { do_something(Some(do_something_handler), cb as *mut _ as *mut c_void) > 0 }
}
```

This will only work if `do_something` does not store the pointer to the callback somewhere. If it does, you need to use a `Box<Fn(..) -> ..>` trait object and leak it after you pass it to the function. Then, if possible, it should be obtained back from your C library and disposed of. It could look like this:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::mem;

use libc::{c_int, c_void};

extern "C" {
    fn set_handler(f: Option<extern "C" fn(x: c_int, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int>, arg: *mut c_void);
    fn invoke_handler(x: c_int) -> c_int;
    fn unset_handler() -> *mut c_void;
}

extern "C" fn do_something_handler(x: c_int, arg: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
    let closure: &mut Box<dyn FnMut(i32) -> bool> = unsafe { mem::transmute(arg) };
    closure(x as i32) as c_int
}

pub fn set_callback<F>(callback: F)
    where F: FnMut(i32) -> bool,
          F: 'static
{
    let cb: Box<Box<dyn FnMut(i32) -> bool>> = Box::new(Box::new(callback));
    unsafe {
        set_handler(Some(do_something_handler), Box::into_raw(cb) as *mut _);
    }
}

pub fn invoke_callback(x: i32) -> bool {
    unsafe { invoke_handler(x as c_int) > 0 }
}

pub fn unset_callback() {
    let ptr = unsafe { unset_handler() };
    // drop the callback
    let _: Box<Box<dyn FnMut(i32) -> bool>> = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr as *mut _) };
}

fn main() {
    let mut y = 0;
    set_callback(move |x| {
        y += 1;
        x > y
    });

    println!("First: {}", invoke_callback(2));
    println!("Second: {}", invoke_callback(2));

    unset_callback();
}
```

Double indirection (i.e. `Box<Box<...>>`) is necessary because `Box<Fn(..) -> ..>` is a trait object and therefore a fat pointer, incompatible with `*mut c_void` because of different size.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately this particular function does not allow passing any user data. So, to make it work I would have to require users to provide an `extern "C"` function as a parameter to my Rust wrapper? Or is there a way to use a trait/object?

Comment: Unfortunately, I see no other way than passing `extern "C"` function. Maybe someone else could suggest something, but it is unlikely.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I've a similar requirement. In my case userdata is passed to callback but it is set using a function like this --> `bindings::mosquitto_user_data_set`. Due to this my closure is getting destroyed by the time callback is invoked and I'm getting garbage on closed variables. Can you please extend the answer with an example of `Box` method that you are suggesting?

Comment: @tez I've added an example.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Thank you very much. I'm little confused about this. I asked a new question explaining my problem. Can you please take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247879/rust-closure-as-callback-for-c-bindings-receiving-garbage-value-in-captured-vari

Comment: In your first example, in `do_with_callback`, why is there no double indirection? Am I missing something, or is there a mistake?

Comment: @Sgeo yep, looks like a mistake. I wonder why Rust even allows this to compile, given that the fat pointer `&mut FnMut(...) -> ...` should not be really convertible to `*mut c_void`. Fixed.

Comment: Why does the first example not work, if the library stores the pointer? I have your second example working, but I don't understand why the first doesn't work.

Comment: Because in the first example the closure is stored on the stack, and goes out of scope once the `do_with_callback` function returns, which in general results in memory deallocation and other resource cleanups. Also, stack memory tends to be reused. If the library stores the pointer somewhere to be called later, it would then call the `do_something_handler` function with an argument pointing to garbage data, which would likely cause crashes or some other nasty behavior.

Answer (score 7):

[The first snippet from Vladimir Matveev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788207/vladimir-matveev) no longer works as written. The size of `&mut FnMut(i32) -> bool` and `*mut c_void` is different and such casts lead to a crash. Corrected example ([playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ceea597e4db02826e42e0ad1488617db&version=nightly&backtrace=0)):

```
extern crate libc;

use std::mem::*;

use libc::c_void;

pub fn run<F>(mut callback: F) -> bool
    where F: FnMut(i32) -> bool
{
    let mut cb: &mut FnMut(i32) -> bool = &mut callback;
    println!("sizeof(cb/*-ptr): {}/{}",
             size_of::<*mut FnMut(i32) -> bool>(),
             size_of::<*mut c_void>());

    let ctx = &mut cb as *mut &mut FnMut(i32) -> bool as *mut c_void;
    println!("ctx: {:?}", ctx);
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    // Convert backward
    let cb2: *mut *mut FnMut(i32) -> bool = unsafe { transmute(ctx) };
    println!("cb2: {:?}", cb2);

    // this is more useful, but can't be printed, because not implement Debug
    let closure: &mut &mut FnMut(i32) -> bool = unsafe { transmute(ctx) };

    closure(0xDEAD)
}

fn main() {
    println!("answer: {}",
             run(|x| {
                 println!("What can change nature of a man?");
                 x > 42
             }));
}
```

Comment: Both of the code snippets in the other answer compile correctly. Are you saying that there's a crash when the program is executed?

Comment: Yes. Just try it in play.rust-lang.org. This site not reports crash, just some `println`ed strings not printed, which say me, that application crashes. Already one the fact that the different quantity `&mut` is used during creation pointer and obtaining closure back the index has to guard.

Answer (score 5):

In C, a function pointer does not have associated context, which is why usually a C callback function usually carry an extra `void*` argument pass the context...

```
typedef bool (*listener_t)(int, int, void* user_data);
bool do_it(void* user_data, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, listener_t listener)
```

... or have an API to let to store the user data...

```
void api_set_user_data(void* user_data);   // <-- caller set the context
void* api_get_user_data();   // <-- callback use this to retrieve context.
```

---

If the library you want to wrap does not provide any of the above, you will need to pass the context via other channels, e.g. via a global variable, though that context will be shared across the whole process:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref REAL_CALLBACK: Mutex<Option<Box<FnMut(c_int, c_int) -> bool + Send>>> = Default::default();
}

extern "C" fn callback(x: c_int, y: c_int) -> bool {
    if let Some(ref mut real_callback) = *REAL_CALLBACK.lock().unwrap() {
        real_callback(x, y)
    } else {
        panic!("<handle error here>");
    }
}

fn main() {
    *REAL_CALLBACK.lock().unwrap() = Some(Box::new(move |x, y| {
        println!("...");
        true
    }));
    unsafe {
        do_it(callback);
    }
}
```

It is also possible to create a [*trampoline function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179521/implementation-of-nested-functions) to stick the context directly in the function, but it is extremely difficult and unsafe.

<sub>*Answer manually migrated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597209/224671*</sub>